# Cauchy sequences through examples in Quantum Mechanics (at the level of the rigor of physicists)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, mathematical-physics

I have just read the definition of a Cauchy sequence:

> A sequence ($\psi_n$) is a Cauchy sequence in a vector space $V$ when $||\psi_n-\psi_m||\to 0$ when $n,m\to\infty$. The limit of every Cauchy sequence $(\psi_n)$ converges to a definite element $\psi\in V$ i.e. $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\psi_n=\psi.$$

But I cannot feel it completely unless I see an example of such a sequence. What is an example of a Cauchy sequence of vectors $(\psi_1,\psi_2,...)$ that we encounter in quantum mechanics?

Comment: Well, since we basically work in Hilbert spaces (which are complete) (ignoring the complications of rigged spaces), every Cauchy sequence is actually convergent, so really you're asking for a convergent sequence. When we expand a wave function as an infinite sum of basis functions (say, in terms of the harmonic oscillator wave functions), this is a convergent sequence in the sense that the sequence of partial sums converges (in the $L_2$ sense) to the wave function.

Comment: @march What forms the sequence here? In your example, should I think of the sequence $(\psi_1,\psi_2,\psi_3...)$ as the sequence of energy eigenfunctions $(\phi_0(x),\phi_1(x),\phi_2(x),...)$? That I'm not sure.

Comment: The sequence that @march stated should be the coefficients of the Fourier series, is it?

Comment: The sequence is the sequence of partial sums, each of which is a *function*.  See SolubleFish's answer.  If the Dirac notation is confusing, just replace each $|n\rangle$ with $\psi_n(x)$ in your head. Note that there's actually not much *physics* in the notion of a Cauchy sequence, since we assume Cauchy sequences are convergent, and all that convergence does is guarantee that the infinite sum makes sense.  It's the expansion *itself* that has physical meaning through the interpretation of the coefficients of the expansion as probability amplitudes for certain projective measurements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a concrete example. For a particle in an infinite potential well of width $a$, the normalized energy eigenvectors are of the form
$$\psi_n(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{a}} \sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{a}\right)$$
Most wavefunctions - such as the $\Psi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}$, corresponding to a uniform spatial probability density throughout the well - cannot be written as a *finite* linear combination of energy eigenvectors.  It *can*, however, be expressed as the sum of the convergent series

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{(2n-1)\pi} \psi_{2n-1} \rightarrow \Psi(x)$$
as illustrated with the following plot of the first $n$ partial sums:
[image]

The sequence of partial sums $\Psi^{(n)}:= \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{(2n-1)\pi}\psi_{2n-1}$ is indeed Cauchy (which can be verified as a nice exercise), as requested.

---

> I have just read the definition of a Cauchy sequence [...]

Note that the proper definition of a Cauchy sequence is that, for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists some $N\in \mathbb N$ such that for **all** $n,m>N$, $\Vert \psi_n-\psi_m\Vert <\epsilon$. In words, given any arbitrarily small tolerance $\epsilon$, if we go far enough along in the sequence we can find a point $N$ past which all of the terms from the $N^{th}$ onward are within $\epsilon$ of one another.

The definition you provide is problematic, in my opinion. In what way do $n,m\rightarrow \infty$?  Do you mean that we hold $n$ fixed, send $m\rightarrow \infty$, and then send $n\rightarrow \infty$ afterward? If that's the case, then we need the sequence to have a well-defined limit which is *a priori* not necessary for a generic Cauchy sequence.  Or we send them both to infinity at the same time? If that's the case, it matters how exactly we do this.

Comment: +1  for the final paragraphs.

Comment: @J. Murray I understand the example, but fundamentally, what is the need for this property? Or what is its physical manifestation? What if we don't demand that Hilbert spaces be complete? I'm trying to understand the role of every property of Hilbert spaces in the physics of QM.

Comment: @EM_1 In finite dimensions, all inner product spaces are complete with respect to the norm topology, so the importance comes in infinite dimensions. Recall that when we compute the probabilities of the various possible outcomes of a measurement, we express the state vector as a linear combination of the corresponding observable's eigenstates and then examine the coefficients. In infinite dimensions, this generally requires a sum of an infinite number of eigenstates, which (unlike the finite case) requires a notion of convergence to define in the first place. [...]

Comment: @EM_1 Without the completeness requirement, we cannot be sure that such an expansion is possible. Completeness implies that any self-adjoint (or more generally, *normal*) operator can be associated to a spectral decomposition which we can use to expand any state vector we choose.

Answer (score 5):

The most common way Cauchy sequence appear is as series. For example, if $|0\rangle, |1\rangle, \ldots ,|n\rangle , \ldots$ is an orthonormal sequence and $\sum |a_n|^2 = 1$, we expect $|\psi \rangle = \sum a_n |n\rangle$ to be a well defined state, ie we would like the limit :
$$\lim_{N\to +\infty} \sum_{n=0}^N a_n|n\rangle$$
to exist.

The sequence $(\sum_{n=0}^N a_n|n\rangle)_{N\in\mathbb N}$ is Cauchy, since :
$$\left\|\sum_{n=0}^{N+p}a_n|n\rangle - \sum_{n=0}^{N}a_n|n\rangle \right\|^2 = \left\| \sum_{n=N+1}^{N+p}a_n|n\rangle\right\|^2 = \sum_{n=N+1}^{N+p}|a_n|^2\overset{N\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$$
Therefore, because we work in a (complete) Hilbert space, the limit we wanted does indeed exist.